# Spring Boot - OAuth2 with Mocked Authroization Server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth

Having a hard time to wrap my head around how to get this specific setup to work. I'm running my authentication server (ghcr.io/navikt/mock-oauth2-server) as a separate container from my api server (Spring Boot Application) but they are on the same network. From the test that executes on my local machine I want to contact the authentication server and get a valid (bearer?) token (without any prompt or login pages) that the api-server validates against the authentication server and finally allows the client to access the api.

First of, is this described setup a valid one for testing the security aspect of my api?

Second, there must be something I'm missing on the api server side as request always throws exception of "Could not obtain the keys" which I can't figure out what exactly it is I need to add. I see 401 in the root of the exception but is it the server or the client that it's meant for? Full stack trace with debug enabled on the api server: https://pastebin.com/e0MPaEnP

**Server:**

applications.yml:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/default
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8080/default/jwks
```

Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().authenticated())
                .csrf(csrfSpec -> csrfSpec.disable()) // Required for implicit flow
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
public class AuthorizationContainer extends GenericContainer<AuthorizationContainer> {
    private static final DockerImageName AUTHORIZATION_IMAGE = DockerImageName.parse("ghcr.io/navikt/mock-oauth2-server:2.0.0");
    private static final int APP_PORT = 8080;
    
    public AuthorizationContainer() {
        super(AUTHORIZATION_IMAGE);

        addFixedExposedPort(APP_PORT, APP_PORT); // Easy of use for curl
        waitingFor(Wait.forHttp("/isalive").forStatusCode(200));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for providing the stack trace. It will also help others to investigate if you can give a minimal project to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Will try to set up a MVP of the issue soon, will comment again when it's ready

Answer (score 0):

To get tokens without prompt, you might use client_credentials flow. If you want to use authorization_code flow, you'll probably have to use an end-to-end test framework like Protractor to emulate user interaction (going to be tricky if multi-factor authentication is activated on your authorization server).

But, I'd advise not to use a test container for an authorization server during unit or integration tests: it is way slower than using mocked `Authentication` with MockMvc or WebTestClient (or without a web client when testing components like @Service or @Repository).

You might find [this article I wrote](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control) useful. You'll find there everything you need to test all access control rules on any type of component. If you opt for the @WithJwt I describe there, you'll even test your JWT authentication converter.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't this just push this type of testing down the road if you mock it in its entirety? Or would the idea be that you run it against a proper authentication server in your QA environment then? Follow up question also but doesn't apply to my current component, which flow would you use for server-to-server authorization?

Comment: the flow to use for server 2 server communication is `client_credentials`. See [this intro to my tutorials for some OAuth2 essentials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials).

Comment: Token decoding and validation is the job of Spring Security, there is no reason to unit test it. What you should unit test is the code you may provide: converter from the decoded and validated JWT payload (a `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt` instance) to an `Authentication` instance, as well as access control rules. `@WithJwt` allows to test both with JSON payload that you can copy from real tokens.